# I can not access my ApiController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create an Api controller used for logging in, which should be used before using my `CustomerController` (Api) to access data.

The problem is that I am getting a 404 error when I try to access my Login method on `AccountController`. I am trying to POST to the `AccountController` as shown in my screenshot below.

Funny thing is that I am able to access my `CustomerController` (Api) without any problem by pointing my browser to `http://localhost:62655/api/customer/cvr/88888888`. **Am I missing a convention or something for the POST request?**

My WebApi route config is:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

And added into my Global.asax:

```
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

My AccountController and CustomerController is looking like so (files merged for brevity):

```
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; private set; }
    private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        }
    }

    public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Login([FromBody]LoginApiViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Username or password is not supplied");

        var user = UserManager.Find(model.Username, model.Password);
        if (user != null && UserManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "Administrator"))
        {
            var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true }, identity);

            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Success");
            return response;
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Wrong login");
    }
}

[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ICustomerService _customerService;

    public CustomerController(ICustomerService customerService)
    {
        _customerService = customerService;
    }

    [ActionName("cvr")]
    public CustomerApiViewModel GetCustomerById(string id)
    {
       var customer = _customerService.GetByCVR(id);
       if (customer == null) throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
       var customerViewModel = Mapper.Map<CustomerApiViewModel>(customer);

       return customerViewModel;
    }
}
```

[image]

The above image returns a 404 error. The program is Fiddler2.

Exception:

> [HttpException]: The controller for path '/api/account/login'
>   was not found or does not implement IController.

**Based on comments, update - (complete Global.asax and RouteConfig (MVC)**

```
 protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    AutoMapperWebConfiguration.Configure();

    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnsureInitialized(); 
}

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "DefaultOnlyAction",
        "{action}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: webapi doesn't know that your Login() method is support to support POST

Comment: From the looks of your Account controller, route and request..they seem fine and you should have received a response...what details do you get in the 404 response's body?...btw, change `WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);` to `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);`

Comment: Even if I rename the action to: Login([FromBody]LoginApiViewModel model) I still recieve a 404. Updated post with response stack strace.

Comment: Also changed the Global.asax without any luck

Comment: I renamed it to PostLogin without any luck.

Comment: Based on your exception, it appears your request is being matched by a MVC route and hence its looking for an implementation of `IController` (MVC) rather than an implementation of `IHttpController` (Web API)...can you share how your Global.asax is?

Comment: Yes, for sure. One moment.

Comment: I have an MVC controller named AccountController, but it inherits from Controller only.

Comment: thanks..i posted an answer..the problem is with your route config ordering..

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Change your configuration to like below...here i moved web api routes before MVC routes...this is because Web API routes are more specific than the generic MVC routes..

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    AutoMapperWebConfiguration.Configure();
}
```

Comment: Yes! This is correct! Now I am hitting my controller! 5 hours of digging around is finally solved, haha.

Comment: This helped me also, I had to move my GobalConfiguration.Configure call before my RouteConfig call and presto, i could access my webapi controller error free.

Comment: This helped me also, I had to remove one of the webapi configurations also, because there were conflict between the MVC routes and the api routes.

Comment: Perfect solution!

Comment: What if my code is not firing any of the other methods?

Answer (score 1):

It is because you didn't define whether the action of controller is [HttpGet] or [HttpPost]. In your case your login action should be like this

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Login([FromBody]LoginApiViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Username or password is not supplied");

    var user = UserManager.Find(model.Username, model.Password);
    if (user != null && UserManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "Administrator"))
    {
        var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true }, identity);

        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Success");
        return response;
    }

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Wrong login");
}
```

And also you need to provide [HttpGet] for your CVR action

Comment: if an action name is not prefixed with verbs like "Get", "Post" etc...the default is POST, so you need not explicitly decorate with `HttpPost` attribute

Comment: Still hitting a 404 error. I can not understand this at all, the CustomerController is hitting just fine using GET, but the account is just a 404 error.

Comment: Could you please try to hit Account with GET method?

Comment: GET returns a 404 as well.

Answer (score 1):

In your Api Class use the Route Notation
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class WebApiController : ApiController
    {

```
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/webapi")] //ROUTE <-- Work for me
    public IEnumerable<ProductViewData> Get()
    {
        //CODE
    }

    // POST api/values
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/webapi/save")] //ROUTE <-- Work for me
    public IHttpActionResult Post(ProductViewData product)
    {
        //CODE
    }
}
```

In your Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

In the WebApiConfig.cs:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "WebApi", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    //FOR User JSON format
    config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(
        new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json")
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Web API methods start with their type for instance rename your method postcvr, this will map to post automatically for you.

[documentation link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: The Customer controller is working as it should, but yes - maybe the best would be to rename that action to GetCVR. Maybe you are refering to renaming the Login action to: Login([FromBody]LoginApiViewModel model)? Still no luck it seems :(

Comment: In this case, its implicit to be POST, so you need not say `PostLogin`